# visual basic.net 2013 database Ms Access 2013

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm having trouble in calculating the book fines visual basic 2013 and the database I'm using is MS Access 2013. Here's my code:

```
    'ADD
    Dim conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\huzai_000\Desktop\HND YEAR 1\HND Year1 assignments\Projects\Library project\Library Management System\Library Management System\Library.accdb")
    conn.Open()

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT into [Book_Return]([Member ID], [Title], [Author], [Edition], [Return Date], [Date Due Back], [Over Due Fine]) Values(@Member ID,@Title,@Author,@Edition,@Return Date,@Date Due Back,@Over Due Fine)", conn)
    cmd.Connection = conn

    If (conn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
        Try
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Member ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Member_IDTextBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TitleTextBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Author", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AuthorTextBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Edition", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = EditionTextBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Return Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = Return_DateDateTimePicker.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date Due Back", OleDbType.Date).Value = Date_Due_BackDateTimePicker.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Over Due Fine", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Over_Due_FineTextBox.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Data Added Successfuly to Book Return", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Data.ToString())
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed")
    End If

    If (Return Date > Date Due Back) Then
        Dim OverDueFine As Date
        OverDueFine = Return Date - Date Due Back
        OverDueFine = Return_DateDateTimePicker > Date_Due_BackDateTimePicker
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what trouble exactly?

Comment: This line `If (Return Date > Date Due Back) Then` is not going to work. Variable names don't have spaces in them, and you haven't initialized those variables. Same for 2 lines lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the text property of the DateTimePicker you need to convert it to a date. I used the Subtract method of DateTime class. What is returned by this method is a TimeSpan. I then used the Days property of the TimeSpan class and multiplied by the fine per day. (I used .50) to get the amount of the fine.

```
        Dim DateReturned As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Text)
        Dim DateDue As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Text)
        If DateReturned > DateDue Then
            Dim DaysLate As TimeSpan = DateReturned.Subtract(DateDue)
            Dim Fine As Double = DaysLate.Days * 0.5
            Debug.Print($"Fine = {Fine.ToString:c}")
        Else
            Debug.Print("Fine = 0")
        End If
```

Comment: Thank you! so much It was a big help. :)